# Подскажите как продолжить повторение кода с самого начала(do while), после нажатия "Ок" в prompt, а "ОТМЕНА" выход

Tags: javascript, циклы

```
let askWhatValute = prompt("Введи название валюты", "uah, eur, usd, rub, zl");
let sum = +prompt("Введи сумму");
let inWhichValute = prompt(
  "В какую валюту конвертировать",
  "uah, eur, usd, rub, zl"
);
let continueAgain;
do {
  switch (askWhatValute) {
    case "uah":
      if (inWhichValute === "usd") {
        alert((result = sum * 0.038));
      } else if (inWhichValute === "eur") {
        alert((result = sum * 0.032));
      } else if (inWhichValute === "rub") {
        alert((result = sum * 2.72));
      } else if (inWhichValute === "zl") {
        alert((result = sum * 0.15));
      }
      break;

    case "usd":
      if (inWhichValute === "uah") {
        alert((result = sum * 25));
      } else if (inWhichValute === "eur") {
        alert((result = sum * 0.86));
      } else if (inWhichValute === "rub") {
        alert((result = sum * 70));
      } else if (inWhichValute === "zl") {
        alert((result = sum * 4));
      }
      break;

    default:
      alert("Проверь правильность написания");
      break;
  }
} while ((continueAgain = prompt("Хочешь повторить?")));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Оно?

```js
let continueAgain;

do {
  let askWhatValute = prompt("Введи название валюты", "uah, eur, usd, rub, zl");
  let sum = +prompt("Введи сумму");
  let inWhichValute = prompt(
    "В какую валюту конвертировать",
    "uah, eur, usd, rub, zl"
  );
  
  switch (askWhatValute) {
    case "uah":
      if (inWhichValute === "usd") {
        alert((result = sum * 0.038));
      } else if (inWhichValute === "eur") {
        alert((result = sum * 0.032));
      } else if (inWhichValute === "rub") {
        alert((result = sum * 2.72));
      } else if (inWhichValute === "zl") {
        alert((result = sum * 0.15));
      }
      break;

    case "usd":
      if (inWhichValute === "uah") {
        alert((result = sum * 25));
      } else if (inWhichValute === "eur") {
        alert((result = sum * 0.86));
      } else if (inWhichValute === "rub") {
        alert((result = sum * 70));
      } else if (inWhichValute === "zl") {
        alert((result = sum * 4));
      }
      break;

    default:
      alert("Проверь правильность написания");
      break;
  }
} while ((continueAgain = prompt("Хочешь повторить?") !== null));
```

Comment: Не работает( После нажатия Отмена-код не повторяется

Comment: как продолжить повторение кода с самого начала(do while), после нажатия "Ок" в prompt, а "ОТМЕНА" - выход....... все верно..... ОТМЕНА - ВЫХОД

Comment: Отмена - выход работает, а если нажать Ок - то не повторяется(

Comment: @AndriiKondysiuk а какой смысл оставлять prompt пустой при вопросе хочешь/не хочешь? Введи значение. Или пусть пользователь задаёт хочет ли он.........в целом конечно я добавил проверку на null (см. отредактированный ответ). Но смысла в таком подходе мало.......в таком случае логично использовать `confirm` а не `prompt`

Comment: Я только учюся о confirm не слышал) но с confirm Отмена не выходит с цикла, а запускает цикл  заново

Comment: все понял, спасибо) !== false -confirm возвращает только true false